# compare date with past day

Tags: python, datetime

```
x=['2020-05-12 20:16', '2020-05-12 20:16', '2020-05-10 20:11', '2020-05-10 20:07', '2020-05-11 20:03', '2020-05-8 20:02', '2020-05-8 20:02', '2020-05-9 20:02',]
@staticmethod    
def compare_time(post_time):
            date_object = datetime.strptime(post_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            past = datetime.now() - date_object
```

How can I edit my function so that it returns `True` if the date not older than yesterday (within 24 hours of current time) else returns False, I feel I am half way there but not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quantify the difference between 2 datetime object, [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is here that

> A `timedelta` object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times.

You want our duration to be lower than 24h/1d so you need `< timedelta(days=1)` or `< timedelta(hours=24)`

```
def compare_time(post_time):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(post_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    past = datetime.now() - date_object
    return past < timedelta(days=1) # from datetime import timedelta
```

Answer (score 2):

test the difference `datetime.now() - date_object` against a `timedelta` of 1 day:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = ['2020-05-12 20:16', '2020-05-12 20:16', '2020-05-10 20:11', 
     '2020-05-10 20:07', '2020-05-11 20:03', '2020-05-8 20:02', 
     '2020-05-8 20:02', '2020-05-9 20:02',]

def compare_time(post_time):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(post_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    return (datetime.now() - date_object) < timedelta(days=1)

for t in x:
    print(t, compare_time(t))
# 2020-05-12 20:16 True
# 2020-05-12 20:16 True
# 2020-05-10 20:11 False
# 2020-05-10 20:07 False
# 2020-05-11 20:03 False
# 2020-05-8 20:02 False
# 2020-05-8 20:02 False
# 2020-05-9 20:02 False
```